# Cannot resize UI components on WindowsForm inherits (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#

My project has some form that are similar for some components: title, istruction for user, some button and label.
I maked a "base" form and, from this, I created a specific form for every functionality: I inherits from "base".
I don't understand why on inherited form, I can't resize every controls on visual designer, that I've inserted (like TextBox, Label or CustomControls, ...).
I read some messages about this problem, but I don't found a workaround.
Do you have any idea?
In older version of Visual Studio this was possible.
Now, I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Matteo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Mat, Thanks for you suggestion. I prepare an example, sure! I don't attached nothing, because I think that problem it's easy to understand. It's very strange: on Visual Studio 2005 this problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Matteo, I've VS 2017 here I'm often using Windows forms for testing.. and I've never seen a resize problem on form controls.. Maybe it's changes since 2005 ? when I create a form in VS2017, I use the rightclick menu Add new Item on my project in Solution Explorer. Then, I choose a Windows Form from the available item templates. When I do that, the form designer immediately appears and also the Toolbox. If the Toolbox is not visible, I use View/Windows/Toolbox to get it. If you do that, you can resize any component, no problem. The name of my form becomes the Form class derived name.

Comment: The designer observes accessibility rules.  Go back to the base form and change the Modifiers property of these controls from Private to Protected.

Comment: Thanks for you time. I tried your suggestions, but doesn't work.
Every controls added on inherits form taken from toolbox, can be moved, but not resizable. I must realize an example, because it's very strange and I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: [SOLVED] Hello everyone; I will not post any examples because I destroy and re-create the project. Now it works well. I do not understand what happened, but it's better this way